# Module Resolution in TypeScript using Globbing Pattern with multiple wildcards

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns, glob

I'm working on an Angular project with the following folder structure (hypothetical):

```
src
└── app
    ├── component1
    │   └── component1.component.ts
    └── component2
        └── component2.component.ts
tsconfig.json
```

In my `tsconfig.json` I'm trying to define a path with globbing patterns in a way that importing from `@components/component1` would resolve to `src/app/component1/component1.component`.

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
OTHER STUFF...

"baseUrl": "src",
"paths": {
  "@components/*": ["app/*/*.component"]
}
```

With this in place, I have the following import in some module/service/etc.:

`import { Component1 } from '@components/component1';`

The error I'm getting at compile time is:

```
ERROR in error TS5062: Substitution 'app/*/*.component' in pattern '@components/*' in can have at most one '*' character.
```

How can I achieve this without causing errors in the TypeScript compiler? What would be the proper way to write the globbing pattern in `tsconfig.json`?

Any help is appreciated.

#### Note

I don't want to do `@components/component1/component1`.

Comment: Try this `app/**/*.component` note the second `/**`. In many node.js libraries it's helping to define as something like `any directory`. Not sure if it help with TS

Comment: @Szarik It didn't work. Same error!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As compiler error says, there cannot be more than one `*` in `paths` entry.

This can potentially be solved with Webpack aliases, possibly via third-party plugin. If the project uses Angular CLI, Webpack configuration has to be ejected.

The problem with importing separate files like `@components/component1/component1` is commonly solved with [barrels](https://angular.io/guide/glossary#barrel), which are `index.ts` files that re-export directory contents:

```
export * from './component1.component';
```

Comment: Even though this is not as convenient as what I was trying to do, still accomplishes the same import syntax. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. This approach is conventional, that's why Angular team came up with special term for index re-exports. It should be noticed that `@components` alias isn't very helpful this way, because directory structure is shallow.

Comment: That’s true, but this directory structure is hypothetical, my actual app is more complex, and also, I’ve set up many aliases for all kinds of imports (directives, services, guards, etc.), so the `@components` alias complies to the standards I’ve defined in my project. Anyway, thanks for the answer, it helped a lot.